In mermaid diagram, how to make sure that the arrow is always attached to the top of a node?
e.g. if I need to draw a diagram like this:
     .....
     :   v
\X/  :  \Y/
 :   :
 :...:

where \X/ and \Y/ are two nodes, and the only arrow link link from \X/ to \Y/ and attached to \Y/ on the top, how to do it?
